# How can I use multiple different versions of NodeJs simultaneously in different Powershell terminals

Tags: node.js, powershell, nvm

I have multiple projects that I have to build for a product I am working on, and each one requires a different, incompatible version of NodeJs for the build tools. There are valid reasons for this that I am not going to get into here; suffice it to say that updating the projects to all run the same version of Node is not an option.

I currently use NVM to switch versions, but this tends to cause headaches, build errors, and bugs when I am working on two or more of these projects simultaneously and I forget to change the node version before running a build.

Is there a way to set the node/npm version to use on a per-terminal basis?